# How to include an external code generator in CMake?

Tags: cmake, gnu-make, flatbuffers

I've been looking into CMake trying to understand it. From what I understand its really good in combining C++ packages.

However, I don't see how to include code generators into it.
With GNU Makefiles, I would write a simple rule:

```
%.h: %.fbs
    flatc ... $< -o $@
```

How do I write this same rule in CMake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike to Make, CMake has neither *pattern* rules nor *automatic variables* which are expanded according to the current *target* or the *command*.

Instead, CMake allows to define a function or a macro, which encapsulates creation of a *target* or a command with corresponded content.

Your command can be wrapped into the following function:

```
function(add_fbs_header name)
  add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${name}.h
    DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${name}.fbs
    COMMAND flatc ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${name}.fbs -o ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${name}.h
    )
endfunction(add_fbs_header name)
```

with fillowing usage:

```
# equivalent to
#   flatc <source_dir>/foo.fbs -o <binary_dir>/foo.h
# with proper dependencies and output.
add_fbs_header(foo)
```

BTW, a functionality for generate headers files using flatbuffers is already provided in [FindFlatBuffers.cmake](https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/blob/master/CMake/FindFlatBuffers.cmake) script, which comes with FlatBuffers package.

---

For include `FindXXX.cmake` script, use `find_package(XXX)`.

Command, created with `add_custom_command`, will be executed only when some target (or other command) depends on the command's OUTPUT. E.g. in the given way:

```
add_fbs_header(foo)
add_executable(my_exe my.cpp foo.h)
```

Comment: Doesn't this cause compilation at configure time of the CMake?

Comment: While `add_custom_command` is processed on *configure* stage, its COMMAND's are run on *build stage*.